# calling Qiime with system call from R

Tags: r, r-markdown, qiime

Hej,

When I try to call `QIIME` with a system call from `R`, i.e

```
system2("macqiime")
```

`R` stops responding. It's no problem with other command line programs though.

can certain programs not be called from `R` via `system2()` ?

> MacQIIME version:
>   MacQIIME 1.8.0-20140103
>
> Sourcing MacQIIME environment variables...
>
> This is the same as a normal terminal shell, except your default
>     python is DIFFERENT (/macqiime/bin/python) and there are other new
>     QIIME-related things in your PATH.

(note that I am primarily interested to call `QIIME` from `R Markdown` with `engine = "sh"` which fails, too. But I strongly suspect the problems are related)

Comment: I really want a way to run macqiime from R! Did you ever find a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, when you call Qiime from unix command line, it usually creates a virtual shell of it`s own to run its commands which is different from regular system commands like ls or mv. I suspect you may not be able to run Qiime from within R unless you emulate that same shell or configuration Qiime requires. I tried to run it from a python script and was not successful.

Comment: I suspect something along those lines, too. I got an answer from the qiime help list now, too, I will look into it later. if it turns out to be the case, Ill accept your answer